$X$ is dense in the one-point compactification $Y=X\cup\{\infty\}$ of $X$
First, the concept of a dense subset in a topological space always leaves me a bit confused. Please check if my argument is correct:

(I) Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $A$ a dense subset in $X$. By definition, we have $\overline{A}=X$, which means that every point $x\in X$ is adherent to $A$. More precisely, this means, in terms of quantifiers: $\forall x\in X$ and $\forall U\in\tau$ such that $x\in U$, we have $U\cap A\neq\emptyset$. Is this correct?


(II) If item (I) is correct, then to show that a given subset $A\subset X$ is dense in $(X,\tau)$, do I need to fix an arbitrary point $x\in X$ and an open set $U\in\tau$ containing $x$ and show that $U\cap A\neq\emptyset$? Is this correct?

Now, regarding the concept of one-point compactification for a locally compact and Hausdorff space $X$. We say that $Y=X\cup \{\infty\}$ is a one-point compactification in the space $X$, and we know that the collection $\varphi=\{U\,|\, U\in \tau\}\cup\{V\,|\, \infty\in V\,; X\setminus V$ compact$\}$ is the unique topology for $Y$ that makes $Y$ compact and Hausdorff.
I'm trying to prove that the space $X$ is dense in $Y$. Please check if what I have so far is correct:

(III) I need to show that $\overline{X}=Y$. It is clear that every point in $X$ is adherent to $X$, so it suffices to show that $\infty$ is adherent to $X$. Is this correct?

To show that $\infty$ is adherent to $X$, let's consider an open set $V\in\varphi$ such that $\infty\in V$. By the definition of $\varphi$, $X\setminus V$ is compact, but since $X$ is not compact, then $X\setminus V \neq X$. Therefore, there must be at least one point in $V\cap X$, and thus, $X$ is dense in $Y$. Is this last argument really that straightforward? I can't visualize another way to say it.
Thank you for your help.

Yes the argument is really that straight forward. In fact you can go one step further to show that a space $X$ is compact if and only if it is not dense in its one point compactification.

Everything correct except "since $X$ is not compact": this should be assumed from the beginning.

Thank you for your help!
